# Displaying products from shopware into the TYPO3

Tags: typo3, shopware, typo3-extensions

How to display shopware6 products in TYPO3 website(TYPO3 version 10) without using the shopware plugin shopware-typo3-connector.

Comment: Do you use composer? There are many libraries to use the API: https://packagist.org/?query=shopware%20api.

Answer (score 0):

With shopware you can use REST API. This means that you will have to create your on extension that access this API and display the products. Here is the API [Shopware API](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/rest-api/).

There is no other way to let TYPO3 know that you want to display something from Shopware without programming it.

Some information from your end are missing. Which TYPO3 version are you using? A quick search on the [Extension Repository (TER)](https://extensions.typo3.org/?L=0&id=1&tx_solr%5Bq%5D=shopware) has found only one extension and is compatible with TYPO3 8. If you re using TYPO3 9 and later then you will have to build your own extension.

The last solution, if it is possible with shopware, is using an iframe but it is hightly discouraged due to performance, DSVGO and styling. It might not match your website style etc.

If you are new to TYPO3 extensions, you can start from here [Creating a First Extension](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/4-FirstExtension/Index.html)

There is a [Slack](https://typo3.slack.com/) community where you can always ask something and get answer much quicker.